# Checking Type Constrains for Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, static

Reading *"Why can’t I define constraints for my template parameters?"* from the [Isocpp FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#constraints) I read the few lines of code provided below. I understand mainly what the code does but I can not make any sense of the constructor in the `Can_copy` struct :

```
template<class Container>
void draw_all(Container& c) {
            typedef typename Container::value_type T;
            Can_copy<T,Shape*>(); // accept containers of only Shape*s
            for_each(c.begin(),c.end(),mem_fun(&Shape::draw));
}
```

and

```
template<class T1, class T2> 
struct Can_copy {
    static void constraints(T1 a, T2 b) { T2 c = a; b = a; }
    Can_copy() { void(*p)(T1,T2) = constraints; }
};
```

**Question** How does the definition of a function pointer to the static member function `constraints` trigger the desired type check?